# Idiomatic list construction

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, idioms

I'm very new to Haskell and functional programming in general, so I don't really know how to make this code idiomatic:

```
type Coord = Double
data Point = Point Coord Coord Coord deriving Show

type Polyline = [Point]

-- Add a point to a polyline
addPoint :: Polyline -> Point -> Polyline
addPoint line p = p:line

line :: Polyline
line = []

constructLine :: Polyline -> Polyline
constructLine line =
    let 
        p1 = Point 2 4 87
        p2 = Point 3 7 2
        p3 = Point 23 4 8
    in addPoint (addPoint (addPoint line p1) p2) p3

main :: IO() 
main = do
    putStrLn ( show (constructLine line))
```

My problem is in the `constructLine` function. If I want to add a lot of points the nested `addPoint` functions are going to be a problem. How can I factor this? And do you see other things that could be improved?

Comment: Provide a function that given a list of points constructs a polyline. For example you could do `addPoints line ps = ps ++ line` or something like that. BTW: you can also call `addPoint` in infix notation.

Comment: The idiomatic way would probably be to ditch `addPoint` and just construct the list directly as `[p3, p2, p1]`, but if you want to keep that abstract then just make your own operator, like `infixr 5 #`, `(#) :: Point -> Polyline -> Polyline`, `(#) = addPoint` (note that I've swapped the argument order here).  The `infixr` line is important, make sure you keep it, but it means you could instead write this as `p3 # p2 # p1 # line`.  If you really want to keep the argument order then do `infixl 5 #` and it would be written as `line # p1 # p2 # p3` instead.

Comment: Note that if you changed the argument order so that it was `addPoint :: Point -> Polyline -> Polyline`, then you could write this as `addPoint p3 $ addPoint p2 $ addPoint p1 line`, which might be sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiple call to addPoints could be replaced by a fold. As suggested in a comment, reversing your addPoint function would make things easier:

```
addPoint' :: Point -> Polyline ->  Polyline
addPoint' p line = p:line
```

So then your constructLine function could build a temporary list of the points to add add use a fold:

```
constructLine :: Polyline -> Polyline
constructLine line =
    let
        p1 = Point 2 4 87
        p2 = Point 3 7 2
        p3 = Point 23 4 8
    in foldr addPoint' line [p3,p2,p1]
```

This does not break the encapsulation (you can replace your implementation of Polyline by something else than a list of Point) and uses the new points in the order they're going to end up at (p3 in front of p2, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `constructLine` example just strikes me as a long-winded version of this:

```
constructLine :: Polyline -> Polyline
constructLine line = [Point 23 4 8, Point 3 7 2, Point 2 4 87] ++ line
```

I don't know if you've come across these yet, but just to be sure:

- `[Point 23 4 8, Point 3 7 2, Point 2 4 87]` is just a list literal.
- `++` is the function to append lists.

Generally, to add multiple elements to a list, what you do is you have a list of the elements that you wish to add, and append that list together with the original list.

This pattern continues. If we notice that `line` is a constant defined to `[]`, then your whole program really is just a long-winded version of this:

```
type Coord = Double
data Point = Point Coord Coord Coord deriving Show

main :: IO () 
main = putStrLn (show points)
     where points = [Point 23 4 8, Point 3 7 2, Point 2 4 87]
```

Basically, if the points' values are known at compilation time, you can just *write* the list, there's no need to go through all this indirection.

Comment: Yes I know this but I wanted to abstract the polyline construction. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: @ElieGnrd: If polylines are conceptually similar to lists but there are invariants that you wish to protect, one simple way is to have conversion functions back-and-forth between the opaque `PolyLine` type and lists of points.  Then a lot of the logic can be done in terms of list operations (very well supported in Haskell), and to create a `PolyLine` you just supply a list.  For example, the `Data.Map.Map` type in the Haskell Platform works like this—one of the most common ways of creating one is to use the function `fromList :: Ord k => [(k, v)] -> Map k v`.